# Exchange 2010 Past employee calendar

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, calendar

We have some employee who have left the company. Email and AD account have been deleted but meetings still show up in rooms calendar. How can i delete them except going on the meeting room calendar and deleting all meetings 1 by 1?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your question looks similar to the article I've posted below.  You may be able to use the powershell commands listed in the article to achieve your goal.

[Microsoft System Center Introduction to Microsoft Automation Solutions](http://exchangeserverinfo.net/?option=com_content&view=article&id=71:how-to-delete-calendar-item-of-exited-user&catid=25:exchange-2003&Itemid=34)

Comment: hmm When i do you command line get-mailbox | export-mailbox... i have an error, the term 'Export-Mailbox' is not recognized.

Comment: You can try this:                                                               Search and delete all content from a particular user (*** Careful this removes all content from a users mailbox including mail, contacts,calendar,ect.)                                                          'get-mailbox “ResMailbox1” |Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'From:"TestUser@contoso.com*"'  -DeleteContent'

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Link is now dead.